# How to Restart self hosted Signalr

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)
```

to host Signalr hub in windows service. For some reason my hub doesn't accept connection after 2-3 day of running, How i can detect it's unresponsiveness and restart it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should find a reason why your Windows Service crashes. Write logs for events, use `try catch` block and write every error to eventlog.

What about control your Windows Service: have a look [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class

Add such like a method:

```
public void StartService()
{
    using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
    {
        try
        {
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Can not Start the Windows Service [{serviceName}]", ex);
        }
    }
}
public void StartOrRestart()
    {
        if (IsRunningStatus)
            RestartService();
        else if (IsStoppedStatus)
            StartService();
    }
```

UPDATE:
If you have problems only with Hub then try to start it from clients such:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.you can set the time based your requirement
});
```

Feel free to add comments with more information from you issue

Comment: window service works fine. it's just hub doesn't working. I have only problem with hub on server side not client side, because it doesn't accept connections.